# layout issues with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I try to layouting a website and get a strange error with Firefox 10.0.9. In IE8 everything works fine.

I want a 2-side Layout:
Left element with 100% height and 200px widght. (framecontentLeft)
Right element with 100% height and maximum width. (framemaincontent)

The problem is, that the jQuery Tab top-bar will be the same height as the complete framecontentLeft.

UPDATED Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Crf/20/

UPDATED CSS:

```
body, html{
height: 100%;
}
#framecontentLeft {          
float: left;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;        
width: 200px;
}
#framemaincontent {
height: auto !important;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;         
}
```

It must be a very commom mistake, but I don't get it.

Thanks for help.
hugi

Comment: This is a CSS issue... You're setting heights as percentages, but percentages of *what*? The important thing to remember, is CSS cascades, so each element sort of inherits from it's parent. To set a percentage-based height, the parent element(s) must have a height set. In this case, it's important to remember to declare a height on the `body` and `html`. I've updated your code: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Crf/16/

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I had this in the orginal code. To much reduced. But the problem with the jQuery is the same. I don't know how to enable jQuery in Fiddle. The top-bar of the jQuery Tab is the same height as the left div (100%).

Comment: you can also use this jquery plugin. http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Comment: You've got jQuery in the jsfiddle. To add additional libraries, select "add resources" from the left-panel.

Comment: Update: Now we see the problem I have: http://jsfiddle.net/k2Crf/20/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug description: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5601

The solution for this is to manipulate the css for the Tab-UI element:
$(".tabs").css("float", "left");

It works for me.